# How to decrypt a .NET Forms Authentication Cookie in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asp.net, .net, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to see if its possible to decrypt a .NET Forms Authentication Cookie in Node.js

The cookie is generated via .NET Framework 4.6
If i check the `machineKey` value - it uses settings:
`decryptionKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` `validation="SHA1"` `decryption="DES"`

And if i look at the .NET source i believe it defaults to the cbc des cipher:
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/descryptoserviceprovider.cs#L90

With IV key length of 8 bytes
and hmac size of 20 bytes

In the case of the ASPX cookie it has format:
`IV + DATA + HMAC`

So if i try something like this below (which when decrypted should be a binary FormsAuthenticationTicket):

```
const COOKIE_CONTENTS = '86F1EDAAE112A4E56EB1DAA75411F07E8D82F648A87F13E8386735610....REDACTED FULL VALUE';
const decryptionKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

const algorithm = 'des-cbc'; 
const key = Buffer.from(decryptionKey, "hex");

let cookie = COOKIE_CONTENTS;
let blob = Buffer.from(cookie, 'hex');
const ivSize = 8;
const hmacSize = 20;

let iv = blob.slice(0, ivSize);
let hmac = blob.slice(blob.length - hmacSize);
let encrypted = blob.slice(ivSize, blob.length - hmacSize);

console.log("Len (cookie):", cookie.length);
console.log("Len (blob):", blob.length);
console.log("IV:", iv, "len:", iv.length);
console.log("HMAC:", hmac, "len:", hmac.length);
console.log("Encrypted:", encrypted, "len:", encrypted.length);

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
let decrypted = Buffer.from(decipher.update(encrypted, 'binary', 'binary') + decipher.final('binary'), 'binary');
```

And it works!

However when the token is generated with httpRuntime setting:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false" maxRequestLength="10240" />
```

I get a failure

```
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

And unfortunately this is the auth tokens i need to decrypt as they are on staging and production systems.

This may be due to the way .NET has changed the way auth is done when you opt into `targetFramework="4.5"`
It has .NET 4.5 “cryptographic improvements”
See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-2/

I think the rundown is that:

- “Purpose” is passed to the crypto routines that describe purpose, we need to provide the same string to decrypt it
- Changes to how Message Authentication Code is stored (MAC)

Some of the .NET source code is referenced here: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Web/Security/Cryptography/Purpose.cs

and also I can see the 4.5 setting block here: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Web/Security/FormsAuthentication.cs#L155

and the code eventually ends up here:
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Web/Security/Cryptography/MachineKeyDataProtectorFactory.cs#L25-L29

but its hard to follow after that. Seems as though 4.5 mode bipasses the DES settings we have passed to it, so who knows what cipher its actually using when in this mode?

Unfortunately I cant just remove the `targetFramework="4.5"` part as this will mean all user tokens will fail after this is rolled out, meaning all users will need to login again which is not acceptable.

Does anyone know more details on how this can be done with a 4.5 “cryptographic improvements” token?
Any ideas on what I am missing with these crypto settings - it would be great if this can be done in Node.js

**UPDATE:**

I have tried what @Sebastian has mentioned and tried to port over some of the python code without success (I *believe* i have written the node code correctly, please let me know if i'm missing something)

eg:

```
function writeUnsignedInt(v, buf, offset) {
  buf.writeInt32BE(v, offset);
}

// conversion of this: https://lowleveldesign.org/2014/11/11/decrypting-asp-net-identity-cookies/
function deriveKey(key, label, context, keyLengthInBits) {
  let labelCount = 0;
  let contextCount = 0;

  if (label) {
    labelCount = label.length;
  }

  if (context) {
    contextCount = context.length;
  }

  const buffer = Buffer.alloc((4 + labelCount + 1 + contextCount + 4));

  if (labelCount > 0) {
    buffer.write(label, 4, 'ascii');
  }

  if (contextCount > 0) {
    buffer.write(context, 5 + labelCount, 'ascii');
  }

  writeUnsignedInt(keyLengthInBits, buffer, 5 + labelCount + contextCount);

  let destOffset = 0;
  let value = parseInt(keyLengthInBits / 8, 10);

  let resultBuffer = Buffer.alloc(value);
  let num = 1;

  while(value > 0) {
    writeUnsignedInt(num, buffer, 0);

    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', key);
    let bufferString = buffer.toString();
    let hashedData = hmac.update(bufferString);

    let generatedHmac = hashedData.digest('hex');
    let count = Math.min(value, generatedHmac.length);
    resultBuffer.write(generatedHmac.substring(0, count), destOffset);

    destOffset += count;
    value -= count;
    num += 1;
  }

  return resultBuffer.toString();
}

const algorithm = 'des-cbc';

let key = Buffer.from(decryptionKey, "hex");
let blob = Buffer.from(cookie, 'hex');
const ivSize = 8;
const hmacSize = 20;

let iv = blob.slice(0, ivSize);
let hmac = blob.slice(blob.length - hmacSize);
let encrypted = blob.slice(ivSize, blob.length - hmacSize);

let dkey = deriveKey(key, 'FormsAuthentication.Ticket', '>Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware\x11ApplicationCookie\x02v1', 64);

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, dkey, iv);
let decrypted = Buffer.from(decipher.update(encrypted, 'binary', 'binary') + decipher.final('binary'), 'binary');
```

I think the main differences is:

1. I need to deal with DES and not AES (as thats what has been set in the Web.Config file) with different IV and key sizes.
2. Im dealing with a forms authentication ticket and not owin auth or anti forgery token.
3. Im taking a stab at what the "label" is, im setting it as ">Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware\x11ApplicationCookie\x02v1" but not sure thats correct (cant find the source code for this)
4. Im not sure I need to do any padding / base64 decoding of the encrypted data, because its in hex format (i basically get the `DATA` part from `IV + DATA + HMAC` and set it as a blob and pass to `decipher.update`)

Comment: I think you're missing the key derivation part (.NET 4.5 uses the NIST SP800-108 key derivation: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/Cryptography/SP800_108.cs). Long time ago, I implemented it in Python: https://lowleveldesign.org/2014/11/11/decrypting-asp-net-identity-cookies/ - maybe you will find it helpful.

Comment: Interesting, ill check it out @Sebastian - do you remember where you got the '>Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware\x11ApplicationCookie\x02v1' and '/System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryToken.v1' from ? I cant find them in the .NET source where these reside

Comment: I probably decompiled the CookieAuthenticationMiddleware middleware. In the article, I was decrypting ASP.NET MVC cookie, so your label will be different. Check https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/Cryptography/AspNetCryptoServiceProvider.cs,3e572502f4a33d80,references and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/Cryptography/Purpose.cs,6395d736fd374b03 (it would be probably one of the purposes listed there)

Comment: Yeah i think i can use `FormsAuthentication.Ticket` as the context of the purpose, but not sure what the label is .. ill try the one you used `>Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware\x11ApplicationCookie\x02v1`